# Magento Unicommerce Integration internal server error

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am trying to use unicommerce with a magento site for stock and order managment i have built for a client the orders are moving to unicommerce without any issues but when unicommerce tries to update the order on magento there is an internal server error that is occurring below is the error information i received from unicommerce. havent been able to resolve this issue for a while I am getting the proper response on

http://store.statusquo.in/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

but unicommerce is unwilling to update the request url to this. They are insisting that the below url which they are using is working fine with other installations.

[store.statusquo.in/index.php/api/v2_soap/index](http://store.statusquo.in//index.php/api/v2_soap/index)

I am in a fix and need a resolution for this.

```
[URL=store.statusquo.in//index.php/api/v2_soap/index, METHOD=POST, HEADERS=null, BODY=<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate soapenv:encodingStyle="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding">
<sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">bba7d1f7d5ea759c798835a3d8630644</sessionId>
<orderIncrementId xsi:type="xsd:string">100000274</orderIncrementId>
<itemsQty xsi:type="urn:orderItemIdQtyArray" soapenc:arrayType="urn:orderItemIdQty[]"><orderItemIdQty><order_item_id>721</order_item_id><qty>1</qty></orderItemIdQty></itemsQty>
<comment xsi:type="xsd:string">STAT30782</comment><email xsi:type="xsd:int">1</email></urn:salesOrderShipmentCreate>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]
```

And response we are getting as

```
[RESULT=The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?